# How can I store a data structure such as a Hashmap internally in Android?

Tags: java, android, storage

In my Android application I'm trying to store a Map structure such as:`Map<String, Map<String, String>>`using internal storage. I've looked into using `SharedPreferences`, but as you know, this only works when storing primitive data types. I tried to use `FileOutputStream`, but it only lets me write in bytes...Would I need to somehow serialize the Hashmap and then write to file?

I've tried reading through http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal but I can't seem to find my solution.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
private void storeEventParametersInternal(Context context, String eventId, Map<String, String> eventDetails){

Map<String,Map<String,String>> eventStorage = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
Map<String, String> eventData = new HashMap<String, String>();
String REQUEST_ID_KEY = randomString(16);
.   //eventData.put...
.   //eventData.put...
eventStorage.put(REQUEST_ID_KEY, eventData);
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(EVENT_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(eventStorage) //This is wrong but I need to write to file for later access..

}
```

What is the best approach for storing this type of a data structure internally in an Android App? Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, I am very new to Android. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`HashMap` is serializable, so you could just use a [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) in conjunction with [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).

To write your `HashMap` to a file:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("myMap.whateverExtension");
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream= new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

objectOutputStream.writeObject(myHashMap);
objectOutputStream.close();
```

To read the `HashMap` from a file:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream  = new FileInputStream("myMap.whateverExtension");
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);

Map myNewlyReadInMap = (HashMap) objectInputStream.readObject();
objectInputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Steve P's answer but it does not work directly and while reading I get a FileNotFoundException, I tried this and it works well.

**To Write,**

```
try 
{
  FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("YourInfomration.ser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(myHashMap);
  oos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**And to Read**

```
try 
{
  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(context.getFilesDir()+"/FenceInformation.ser");
  ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
  Map myHashMap = (Map)objectInputStream.readObject();
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException | IOException | ClassCastException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing:

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(EVENT_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
s.writeObject(eventStorage);
s.close();
```

Reading is done in the inverse way and casting to your type in readObject